# innerHTML of dynamically added element not updating in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic

I'm modifying a dynamically created input element by setting the innerHTML, when I view the element in the DOM Inspector I can see that the values I passed are in the input. However, I can't see it on the page? Is there a refresh() function that I should be calling after setting the value?

I have tried innerText, and value and gotten the same results.

Here is how I am setting it:

```
$("input[name='group']")[0].innerHTML = groups;
```

(as far as the JS set and the JQuery selector I have found chrome plugins to be fickle this way)

Answer (score 4):

`input` elements don't contain HTML. They have `value`s.

No, you don't need to refresh anything, the change should show up as soon as the JavaScript finishes running (e.g., the event handler completes) and the browser has a moment to update the display. If you're doing this in a tight loop or something, you won't see the results until the end of the loop, but I didn't immediately get the sense that was what you were doing — unless you're single-stepping through the code in the dev tools? You won't see the refresh as you're single-stepping.

If not that, could it be that the element doesn't exist (yet) when you're calling your code? Remember that if your code is in a `script` element that's in the HTML *before* the element you're trying to update, you have to be sure you make it wait to run until the rest of the page has been parsed (using a [`ready`](http://jsbin.com/ovike4) callback, for instance). Alternately, just do [what the YUI folks recommend](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and put your `script` tag at the end of the `body`.

Here's a working example:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  setInterval(function() {
    $("input[name='group']")[0].value = "Updated " + new Date();
  }, 500);

});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ovike4)

Breakdown:

- Waiting until the DOM is ready (by putting my code inside the function I pass into `jQuery`; this is a shorthand way of writing [`jQuery(document).ready(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)).
- Set up an interval timer to update every 500ms.
- Within the interval callback, look up the input element with the name "group" and update its value.

---

**Update**: Here's a simpler series of examples that demonstrate the whole "does the element exist yet?" thing:

**Example 1:**

```
<form>
  <input type='text' name='group' value='original value' size='60'>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // This works, because it's _after_ the element
  // it operates on
  $("input[name='group']")[0].value = "Just one update: " + new Date();
</script>
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ivafo4)

**Example 2:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // This FAILS, because it's _before_ the element
  // it operates on
  $("input[name='group']")[0].value = "Just one update: " + new Date();
</script>
<form>
  <input type='text' name='group' value='original value' size='60'>
</form>
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ivafo4/2)

**Example 3:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // This works, because although this script tag is before
  // the element, we're using `ready` to wait until the DOM
  // is ready
  $(function() {
    $("input[name='group']")[0].value = "Just one update: " + new Date();
  });
</script>
<form>
  <input type='text' name='group' value='original value' size='60'>
</form>
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ivafo4/3)

Comment: thanks for all your help. so, I am working on a plugin... so the JS is before the element. I don't know that I can change that, I could always mess around with the existing page dom and inject a script at the end. I tried testing at an interval, however, and no luck. I'm lost ask to the cause of this.

Comment: @Sara: If you're writing a plug-in, it's best if you have the page author trigger your code explicitly (e.g., it's up to them how and when to make it happen). That would be the standard approach. But if you want it to be automatic, use the `ready` event as in Example 3.

Answer (score 1):

Text box has no inner HTML. You need to set its value:

```
$("input[name='group']").val(groups);
```